# Display signature image in email

Tags: php, jquery, html

I was looking for a signature pad and came across a plugin by Thomas Bradley.
I'm trying ti display the signature as an image in an email. All I get is an image code

Client signature:

[{"lx":69,"ly":44,"mx":69,"my":43},{"lx":68,"ly":43,"mx":69,"my":44},{"lx":68,"ly":44,"mx":68,"my":43},{"lx":69,"ly":48,"mx":68,"my":44},{"lx":72,"ly":55,"mx":69,"my":48},{"lx":77,"ly":67,"mx":72,"my":55},{"lx":85,"ly":82,"mx":77,"my":67},{"lx":90,"ly":96,"mx":85,"my":82},{"lx":93,"ly":107,"mx":90,"my":96},{"lx":95,"ly":114,"mx":93,"my":107},{"lx":97,"ly":117,"mx":95,"my":114},{"lx":98,"ly":117,"mx":97,"my":117},{"lx":102,"ly":113,"mx":98,"my":117},{"lx":110,"ly":102,"mx":102,"my":113},{"lx":120,"ly":86,"mx":110,"my":102},{"lx":131,"ly":68,"mx":120,"my":86},{"lx":139,"ly":53,"mx":131,"my":68},{"lx":143,"ly":48,"mx":139,"my":53},{"lx":145,"ly":47,"mx":143,"my":48},{"lx":147,"ly":49,"mx":145,"my":47},{"lx":154,"ly":55,"mx":147,"my":49},{"lx":159,"ly":62,"mx":154,"my":55},{"lx":161,"ly":68,"mx":159,"my":62},{"lx":162,"ly":73,"mx":161,"my":68},{"lx":162,"ly":75,"mx":162,"my":73},{"lx":162,"ly":74,"mx":162,"my":75},{"lx":166,"ly":66,"mx":162,"my":74},{"lx":173,"ly"
     :53,"mx":166,"my":66},{"lx":180,"ly":37,"mx":173,"my":53},{"lx":182,"ly":27,"mx":180,"my":37},{"lx":182,"ly":23,"mx":182,"my":27},{"lx":178,"ly":31,"mx":182,"my":23},{"lx":169,"ly":45,"mx":178,"my":31},{"lx":163,"ly":59,"mx":169,"my":45},{"lx":161,"ly":66,"mx":163,"my":59},{"lx":163,"ly":68,"mx":161,"my":66},{"lx":170,"ly":64,"mx":163,"my":68},{"lx":183,"ly":55,"mx":170,"my":64},{"lx":205,"ly":43,"mx":183,"my":55},{"lx":230,"ly":32,"mx":205,"my":43},{"lx":267,"ly":22,"mx":230,"my":32},{"lx":300,"ly":12,"mx":267,"my":22},{"lx":307,"ly":9,"mx":300,"my":12},{"lx":308,"ly":8,"mx":307,"my":9}]

---

PHP Code:

```
    <?php 
require_once("session.php");

  require_once("class.user.php");
  $auth_user = new USER();

  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

  $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
  $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));

  $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    if (!$_POST['output']) {
      $error = "<br>- Please enter your signature!";
    }

  if ($error) {
    $result = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Whoops, there is an error. Please correct the following: $error</div>";
  } else {
    mail("albetws@gmail.com", "Request form", "From: ".$_POST['username']."

      Message: ".$_POST['message']."

      Client signature: ".$_POST['output']);

    {
      $result = "<div class='alert alert-success text-center' role='alert'>
      <p>Thank you for your request.</p>
      <p>No request conformation within 1 hr call the receiver</p>
      <p>Please <a href='logout.php?logout=true'>Logout</a>.</p>
      </div>";
    }
  }

}

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="signature/assets/jquery.signaturepad.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../assets/flashcanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Client Approval</h2>
                    <p class="text-center"><a href="option.php">Return to Main Menu </a>&nbsp;&sol;&nbsp; <a href="logout.php?logout=true">Logout</a></p>
                    <?php echo $result;?>
                        <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="sigPad">

                            <p class="drawItDesc">Insert signature in the box below.</p>
                            <div class="sig sigWrapper">
                                <canvas class="pad" height="150"></canvas>
                                <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group input-group btn-margin">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="button" name="clear" class="form-control btn btn-primary clearButton" value="Clear signature">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group input-group btn-margin">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Submit signature">
                            </div>

                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="signature/jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var options = {
                defaultAction: 'drawIt',
                drawOnly: true,
                lineTop: 135,
                lineMargin: 20,
                penColour: '#000'
            }

            $('.sigPad').signaturePad(options);
        });
    </script>
    <script src="signature/assets/json2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

I used a litte time befor szimek pad signature under MIT License from github.com web site,
otherwise i don't see in your code in wich format you save you image.

Comment: how is this supposed to be an answer?